# SSRS XML Data Source How do I query XML with multiple parent child hierarchy

Tags: reporting-services, xmldatasource

How do I query XML data source in SSRS so that two parent-child hierarchies are returned?
For example

```
<parent>
    <child1>
        <child2>
            <child3>
                <a1>1</a1>
                <b1>2</b1>
            </child3>
            <child4>
                <c1>1</c1>
                <d1>2</d1>
            </child4>
        </child2>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

How do I query this XML so that I get a1,b1,c1,d1 as a result set?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

The below example should give you the results you are looking for:

```
<Query>
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="True">
parent{}/child1{}/child2{child3 {a1,b1}, child4{c1,d1}}
</ElementPath>
</Query>
```