# How to Get Multiple Values in an XML Query in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: xml, reporting-services, xml-parsing, ssrs-2008

I've been following [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365158%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). And I've been able to get the following results.

When I use this query:

```
page{}/workgroups{}/workgroup{name,agents,queue{agentsloggedin,agentsavailable,callswaiting}}
```

this is the result:

```
name    | agents  | agentsloggedin  | ageentsavailable  | callswaiting
--------|---------|-----------------|-------------------|-------------
Sales   | 7       | 4               | 0                 | 3
Support | 5       | 5               | 2                 | 0
Admin   | 2       | 1               | 0                 | 1
```

So you see it gets the `name` and quantity of `agents` for each `workgroup`, and it goes into the `queue` element for each `workgroup` to get the the rest of the data.

And can go one step deeper like this:

```
page{}/workgroups{}/workgroup{name,queue{agentsavailable,agentsloggedin,callsanswered,callswaiting,currentshift{averagetalktime,averagewaittime,numberanswered,numberofcalls}}}
```

And get `currentshift` data too.

Now, I'm able to do all that because each level down that I went to get data from (`queue`,`currentshift`) has only 1 instance. But when I want to get multiple instances of an element like this:

```
page{}/workgroups{}/workgroup{name,queue{currentshift{servicelevels{}/servicelevel{key,value}}}}
```

in which I want to get the `key` and `value` for each of the `servicelevel` elements (there are 7 total) for each of `Sales`, `Support` and `Admin`, it gives me a syntax error saying that **it expects a '}' at character 70** which is the `/` before `servicelevel`.

What confuses me is that I'm trying to do the same as I did before for `workgroups{}/workgroup` and that one worked fine.

Here's a screenshot of the XML tree.

[image]

Note: this seems to be the question in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108741/ssrs-xml-data-source-how-do-i-query-xml-with-multiple-parent-child-hierarchy) too.